# Loading exteral file with load(), modifying and then displaying with fancybox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I'm trying to load an external file after the click of a button, modifying some html of the external file and then displaying it through the fancybox plugin.I have been trying for days now to do this and no success.

A button

```
<a id="preview" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Preview</a>
```

Then some code to load the external html file into an element whose display is off (I know this is wrong, I don't know how else to do it). Then, I try to open this element with fancybox.

```
$('#preview').click(function() {
  $('#loader').load("demo/external.html", function(page) {
     $.fancybox.open({ content: $('loader'), type: iframe});
  })
});
```

As you can tell, I'm an amateur at this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: if you are using `iframe` type, wouldn't be easier to link to that file in your anchor directly to open it in fancybox? ... on the other hand, if you want to load that file into your document because it will use existing css declarations then use `type: "ajax"` instead

Answer (score 0):

With more research I found that everything can be done through the [Fancybox API](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs). I used the beforeShow to modify what I wanted on the external page. `$('.fancybox-iframe')` was used to access the contents.

```
$.fancybox({
    'href': 'demo/external.html',
    'type': 'iframe',
    'autoSize': true,
    beforeShow: function () {
      $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#name').text(name);
    }
  });
```